# apostrophe-cms Creating your own layout.html

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In the 'Getting Started Guide' under the heading 'Editable Global Content' the below code block is presented.  My question is, should the first statement in the code block actually be {% afterMain %} in described scenario?

```
    {% block main %}
      <div class="main-content">
        {{ apos.singleton(data.global, 'footer', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
          toolbar: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Styles', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
        }) }}
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

The code block works great and as I would expect when I make the described change and add the entire block to my freshly created 'layout.html' file.  But, as a newbie if I am not understanding the intent and the first block statement is correct as is and I need to be corrected please do.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of getting started the block you override doesn't really matter, it's just a predefined space to hook into.

The Apostrophe boilerplate assumes you want to breakup your templates in a way that takes advantage of a dedicated file for defining a website header and footer (`beforeMain` and `afterMain`). Extending `outerLayout.html` and overriding `main` keeps that extension file (`layout.html` in your case) small and specific to the purpose of the template.

That said, the blocks are yours to override, name, and structure as you want. Comb back through the initial scaffolding of `outerLayoutBase` and `outerLayout` to understand what will be output.